# how to melt a dataframe -- get the column name in the field of melt dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, melt

I have a df as below

```
     name       0    1    2    3    4
 0   alex      NaN  NaN  aa   bb  NaN
 1   mike      NaN  rr  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2   rachel    ss  NaN  NaN  NaN  ff
 3   john      NaN  ff  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

the melt function should return the below

```
     name      code
 0   alex      2   
 1   alex      3   
 2   mike      1  
 3   rachel    0  
 4   rachel    4
 5   john      1
```

Any suggestion is helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps: melt, dropna, sort column `name`, reset index, and finally drop any unwanted columns

```
In [1171]: df.melt(['name'],var_name='code').dropna().sort_values('name').reset_index().drop(['index', 'value'], 1)
Out[1171]:
     name code
0  alex    2
1  alex    3
2  john    1
3  mike    1
4  rachel  0
5  rachel  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 df.unstack().reset_index().dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index('name').unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Code'}).dropna().drop(0,axis =1)[['name','Code']].sort_values('name')
```

output will be

```
name    Code
alex    2
alex    3
john    1
mike    1
rachel  0
rachel  4
```